# how to print specific number of digits in c++?For example ,printing 8 digits totally(before+after decimal point combined)

Tags: c++

how to print specific number of digits in c++?For example ,printing 8 digits totally(before and after decimal point combined) 
Edit: For further clarification, setprecision sets the digits when i have decimal digits to display.I want to display integer 30 also as 30.000000 ,in 8 digits.
The setprecision command puts fixed no. of digits after decimal and i don't want that. 
In short , I want an alternative of c command printf("%8d",N) in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the c++ header `iomanip` what you want is the `setprecision()` function:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << 12.3456789 << std::endl;
```

outputs `12.346`. It also has other modifiers you can find [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/)
**EDIT**
If you want to print trailing 0s, you need to also use `std::fixed`. This says to use that number of digits, regardless of whether or not they are significant. If you want that to be the total number, you could figure out the size of the number, then change the precision you set it to based on that, so something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    double input = 30;
    int magnitude = 0;

    while(input / pow(10, magnitude))
    {
        ++magnitude;
    }

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8 - magnitude) << input << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This returns `30.000000`. You can also do something similar by outputting to a string, then displaying that string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `setprecision()` function from include `iomanip` and `fixed` like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double d = 1000;
    double t = d;
    int dc=0;
    while(t>0.9)
    {
        dc++;
       t= t/10;
    }
    cout<<"dc:"<<dc<<endl;
    cout << fixed;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(dc);
    std::cout << d;
    return 0;

}
```

The `setprecision()` will not  work fine every time So you have to use `fixed` as well.

Comment: Updated the ans accordingly try it.

Comment: your update works for the fixed number but i don't know what output i will get , i just have to print 8 digits of output.The setprecision thing puts fixed number of digits after decimal,but if i have 4 digits before decimal ,i only need 4 after that